# Make JQuery button appear pressed; ie change theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI buttons and used [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to do all the fancy color stuff. I'm currently looking for a way to present a button that does nothing except appear pressed.

I assume that there is a style attribute that I can use to just change the colors from default state to pressed state, but I am really struggling to find it. I also searched for a way to set the button to a "selected" state, without much luck. Either method works equally well.

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: $("#buttonName").toggleClass("ui-state-active"); gives the desired colors. However, a click on the button will revert to default colors. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: There is no `select` event for button. There are, however, [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some comments, I've discovered a method that that results in the desired behavior. It seems like far from the best method though.

```
$("#button-id").button().addClass("ui-state-active");
$(document).mousemove(
        function(event){
            $("#button-id").button().addClass("ui-state-active");
        });
```

I guess continually resetting the class isn't the worst.

Note that any event I tried to bind to the button resulted in a reversion to original colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try justt adding the active class.

```
$("#buttonName").addClass("ui-state-active");
```

Comment: This gives the same behavior as    $("#buttonName").toggleClass("ui-state-active"); A click will still revert to default.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are need to disable the button, and set the css style to active, so:

> $('#buttonName').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("ui-state-active");

should do the trick

EDIT

Since you don't want to disable the field:

```
$('#buttonName').addClass("ui-state-active").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This works reasonably well and I don't mind going there if I have to. However, the look of a disabled button is dis-preferred over that of an active one.

Comment: I tried out your edit. The color still reverts after any mouseover or click. I can only assume that the color is not a result of an event, or .preventDefault() would be working in this occasion.